# Sql Query Not Working with php variables

Tags: php, mysql

My Sql Query Returning Empty results set. Is there any Mistake in format. I am Using some php variables inside the query..

```
public function getBlockDate($month,$year){
    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
    $time_from="00-00-00";
    $time_to="23-59-59";
    $sql = 'select * from blocks WHERE date LIKE "'.$year.'-'.$month.'%" AND (time_From="'.$time_from.'" AND time_to="'.$time_to.'")';

    return $connection->getArray($sql);
}
```

***Here time_from and time_to table columns are of time type***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL query

```
$sql = 'select * from blocks WHERE date LIKE "'.$year.'-'.$month.'%" AND (time_From="'.$time_from.'" AND time_to="'.$time_to.'")';
```

`'` single quotes are missing over `$time_from` and `$time_to`

**EDITED QUERY**

```
$time_from="00:00:00";
$time_to="23:59:59";
$sql = 'select * from blocks WHERE date LIKE "'.$year.'-'.$month.'%" BETWEEN (time_From="'.$time_from.'" AND time_to="'.$time_to.'")';
```

also change the `-` with `:` in your `$time_from` and `$time_to` variables

Comment: its too returning empty result sets.. i forgot to add the single quotes here in code..

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You didn't put quotas right at the AND clause.
Also when using LIKE in your query be sure to place the wildcard correctly. In your case you are looking for records in date column whose start with year-month then there's your time.

```
 $time_from="00-00-00";
 $time_to="23-59-59";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE date LIKE '".$year."-".$month."%' AND (time_From='".$time_from."' AND time_to='".$time_to."')";
```

Comment: Buddy its not working... The Only query its working is  $sql = "SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE date LIKE '".$year."-".$month."%'";

Answer (score 0):

Convert date and time to universal format and then  query using it.